Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync() returns a malformed Graph mail ID when invoked in Outlook throuhg an Outlook add-in on Windows (new UI)
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync() returns a malformed Graph mail ID for the first time when a new email is being composed.
When the issue is observed:

Open Outlook on Windows (new UI).
Compose a new email.
Open a taskpane add-in that internally invokes Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync() right after clicking on "New email".
The Graph mail ID returned is malformed (it looks something like this: "clientid:ea1a04f8-509e-...").

Platform:
This behavior is observed in Outlook on Windows (new UI).
The taskpane add-in is running in compose mode.
Expected behaviour:
saveAsync() should ideally consistently return the same Graph mail ID
